# How to write text in AutoCAD using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I want to add some text to AutoCAD with an Excel macro using VBA, the format I want is

```
    BOÓ
P.K. xxx.xxx
------------
```

Here, `----` means that `P.K. xxx.xxx` is underlined text and `xxx.xxx` is a numeric value.

The problem is that I don't know how to apply this format to a text.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you wish to create a set of single-line text objects (a.k.a. `DTEXT`), or a single multiline text object (a.k.a. `MTEXT`) in AutoCAD.

#### Single-Line Text (DTEXT)

For single-line text, underline is achieved by preceding the content which is to be underlined with the case-insensitive code `%%U`, e.g.:

```
%%UP.K. xxx.xxx
```

Will yield:

[image]

If you wish to partially underline a section of the text content (as opposed to the entire content of the text object), you would surround the section to be underlined with `%%U` delimiters, e.g.:

```
%%UP.K.%%U xxx.xxx
```

Would yield:

[image]

### Multiline Text (MTEXT)

To apply underline formatting to a section of content held by a multiline text object (MTEXT), you would embed the appropriate [MText Formatting Codes](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-7D8BB40F-5C4E-4AE5-BD75-9ED7112E5967) into the text content, in this case the desired result could be achieved using:

```
BOÓ\P{\LP.K. xxx.xxx}
```

Here:

- `\P` yields a new line between `BOÓ` and `P.K. xxx.xxx`
- `{\L...}` underlines the text enclosed within the curly braces.
  (you can alternatively use `\L` and `\l`)